# Splitting values into similarly distributed evenly sized groups

Tags: algorithm, grouping

Given a list of scalar values, how can we split the list into K evenly-sized groups such that the groups have similar distributions? Note that simplicity is strongly favored over efficiency.

I am currently doing:

```
sort values
create K empty groups: group_1, ... group_k
while values is not empty:
    for group in groups:
        group.add(values.pop())
        if values is empty:
            break
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about how evenly the groups should be sized, and how similar their distributions should be ?

Comment: By even, each group should have floor(num_values / K), except for one group which contains the remainder. The distributions should be as similar as possible.

Comment: BTW, since you are using a python-like pseudocode, a python equivalent of your pseudocode is `[sorted(values)[i::k] for i in range(k)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation on what @m.raynal came up with that will work well even when `n` is just a fairly small multiple of `k`.

1. Sort the elements from smallest to largest.
2. Create `k` empty groups.
3. Put them into a [Priority Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) sorted from least elements to most, then largest sum to smallest.  (So the next element is always the one with the largest sum among all of those with the fewest elements.)
4. For each element, take a group off of the priority queue, add that element, put the group back in the priority queue.

In practice this means that the first `k` elements go to groups randomly, the next `k` elements go in reverse order.  And then it gets clever about keeping things balanced.

Depending on your application, the fact that the bottom two values are spaced predictably far apart could be a problem.  If that is the case then you could complicate this by going "middle out".  But that scheme is much more complicated.

Comment: I'd call it an improvement more than a variation, that's actually way more clever than what i proposed. It'll distribute the items better, with a `O(n.log n)` cost that was already paid when sorting.

Comment: Thank you for this effective method. However, I don't follow your "middle out" comment. Could this method be improved if the data distribution is specified? My data is bimodal and roughly between 0 and 1, with most (~80%) of the data occurring either close to 0 or close to 1, with the remainder uniformly distributed in between.

Comment: @tmakino Imagine  what would happen if your data was normally distributed.  Then the distribution of the bottom 2 values in everyone's left tail would be noticeably weird.  In a middle out approach you'd assign values from the middle, and then bounce back and forth, adding one value above the middle to everyone, one below.  However that approach would make no sense for a bimodal distribution like the one that you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to (somehow) distribute values evenly.
Let's assume your array of scalars `A` is of size `n`, with `n` being a multiple of `k` to make it more simple.
One way could then be :

```
sort(A)
d = n/k
g = 0
for i from 0 to d-1 do {
  for j from 0 to k-1 do {
    group[(j+g) % k].add(A[k*i + j])
  }
  g ++
}
```

You then add the first k elements to the groups `1, ..., k`, the k following to the groups `2, ..., k, 1`, then `3, ...k, 1, 2` etc.

It would not work well if `k² > n`, in this case you should not increment `g` by 1, but by a larger value close to `k/d`. If `k` is almost `n`, then this algorithm becomes simply useless.

This gives absolutely no guarantee about an even distribution of the scalars if some extreme values were to be in A. But in the case `A` itself would be somehow well distributed, and `n > k²`, then it would somehow distribute the values among the k groups.

It has at least the advantage of running in `O(n)` once `A` is sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea. I noticed that if A = [1, 2, 3, ..., n], then your method has the property that at the end of each iteration of adding k elements to the k lists, the lists have equal sum. Was this your intention?

Comment: It was not my original intention, I realized it while writing the pseudo-code. The subset sums problems being NP-complete, I just went for a naive and direct approach to the problem, to have an efficient method.